# How to select the most recent 10 records

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a mysql database. How do I select the most recent 10 records? Im not storing timestamps. But the most the recent records are the ones at the bottom rite? Also. How so I get the next ten , the next ten and so on on clicking a button. Kinda like a bunch of forum posts. The recent ones show up first.

Comment: You need *some* column to derive the sorting order from, i.e. a time stamp/date or an auto-incrementing `int` column. mySQL does not have a built-in "row number" value like other DMBSs

Comment: If you want to get the most recent records you should store timestamps.

Comment: isnt there any way to select from the bottom? Sorry for the crude lingo

Comment: MySQL (among other RDBMSes) does not store records in any order. Ordering only comes about when you add an `ORDER BY` clause to your queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column you can order by that in descending order then limit by 10.

But I suggest you store timestamps and order by that instead so you *know* you're sorting your records according to date, and not some other value that *coincides* with date of insertion.

Comment: same question as above.. This will order the whole result if im not wrong?

Comment: Use an index, it'll speed it up much faster.

Comment: @Ram `LIMIT 10` (with an index) will probably undergo some internal optimizing.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have an auto increment column as a primary key you can use this column and to order by desc

```
select * from table order by id desc  limit 10
```

otherwise you have a very poor database design

Comment: thanks for this. But if my database is large wont this query be overkill?

Comment: I think this is a completely separate question and already discussed on SO

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @BoltClock mentioned, prequerying the maximum ID might help the engine with what other records are retrieved... ie: if you have a million records, and most recent 10, I don't know if it will still try to query out the million, order them, and THEN dump it..  I would try something like

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      YT.*
   from 
      ( select max( IDColumn ) as MaxOnFile
           from YourTable ) PreQuery,
      YourTable YT
   where 
      YT.IDColumn >= PreQuery.MaxOnFile -10
   order by
      YT.IDColumn DESC
   limit 10
```

However, if for some reason, records are allowed to be deleted, you may opt to subtract a little farther back than the -10... but at least this way, the system won't even TRY to process all the other records...